# Output two columns mysql

Tags: mysql, multi-table

I got mySQL query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products_description pd 
LEFT JOIN products zp 
   ON pd.products_id = zp.products_id 
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

This simply joins two tables together, and outputs columns and rows based on the same product id. Now I need only to narrow the columns to two, `column_a` AND `column_b`

How do I go about it?

@EDIT
When two tables are joined am unable to get primary key in order to edit the table. How do I go around it to have primary key (unique) and make the table editable when joined.

Comment: If you just want to return `column_a` and `column_b`, then don't use `select *` use `select column_a, column_b...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, `SELECT pd.column_a, pd.column_b`

```
SELECT pd.column_a, pd.column_b
FROM products_description pd 
LEFT JOIN products zp 
   ON pd.products_id = zp.products_id 
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

Comment: This is the working output :) Thanks

`SELECT products_name, products_weight
FROM products_description pd 
LEFT JOIN products zp 
   ON pd.products_id = zp.products_id 
LIMIT 0 , 1000`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_a, column_b
FROM products_description pd 
LEFT JOIN products zp 
   ON pd.products_id = zp.products_id 
LIMIT 0 , 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

you need just to select those two columns

```
  SELECT column_a , column_b
  FROM products_description pd 
  LEFT JOIN products zp 
  ON pd.products_id = zp.products_id 
  LIMIT 0 , 1000
```